# Active Reports 7 - How to get the height of a detail section filled with data

Tags: activereports, propertyinfo

Is there a way to get/set the height of the detail section after it has been fed with data ?

The only height I get is the one I set on the property of my detail section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any direct way to determine the height of the data rendered in the Detail section. However, a workaround for you is to create a counter and determine how many times the Detail Section is being rendered. Since you already know the height of the Detail Section, the available height or the data-occupied height can be calculated by multiplying the value of counter with the value of the static height of the Detail Section.

A similar implementation id discussed [here](http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/subreport-conditional-page-break/) and you may also download a working sample from the mentioned forum post.

Regards,
Mohita

Answer (score 0):

use detail Format event to set the height of the detail section.  for example;

this.detail1.Height = detailSectionHeight;

detail section height can be computed based on what Mohita mentioned in the previous post or can be set to any value that you wish.  In concept, detail section gets rendered once for every row of the data from a table.

Format event:
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Section~Format_EV.html

Section Events:
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/ReportEvents.html